# How to add a string literal as one selected column for select queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I want to have query like below

```
select "RETRY" as code , name from process ;
```

then the results are

```
code |  name
_____________

RETRY  PX1
RETRY  PX1
RETRY  PX3
RETRY  PX4
RETRY  PX5
```

I want to add one string literal as column for all rows returned by select query. I am trying this in PostgreSQL, but getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "RETRY" does not exist
  Position: 8
```

yny idea how to do this in a PostgreSQL select query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

double quote refers column name of that table thats why you are getting error you have to use single quote

```
select 'RETRY' as code , name from process ;
```

Answer (score 3):

String literals need to be [enclosed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) in single quotes in SQL:

```
select 'RETRY' as code, name 
from process;
```